# Large Identifier Uniqueness Across Table

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

We use `NEWSEQUENTIALID` to generate `uniqueidentifier` as table ID.
Issue is raised after server reset as the seed of it is modified and **sequentiality** breaks.

Is there another suggested solution to achieve large identifier uniqueness for a table?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity values, sequence values, and sequential uniqueidentifier values are never guaranteed to be generated without gaps.

Having said that, if you're using the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` (or `IDENTITY`, or even a `SEQUENCE`) for a primary key column, why do you care if the values generated are sequential.  As long as they are unique, and they are guaranteed to be, what's the problem with gaps between those values?

If you're using that value in some way to confirm correct process, like an invoice number, where you must guarantee each number is sequential, then you'd probably want to use a `SEQUENCE` that uses no caching.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.my_sequence
AS int
START WITH -2147483647
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CYCLE
NO CACHE;
```

The `NO CACHE` directive instructs SQL Server to generate numbers from the sequence one-at-a-time, which results in lower performance, but prevents the sequence from missing numbers due to server shutdown, etc.

Since my sequence definition above uses an `int` data type, and starts with -2147483647, it will generate 4,294,967,296 unique numbers before an error is generated by the `NO CYCLE` property.  If you remove the `NO CYCLE` property, the sequence will reset to -2147483647 once it hits 2147483648.  It that is not a large enough numeric range, you could always use a `bigint` as the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into Jimmy Nilsson's COMBs? Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155454/performance-value-of-comb-guids

Or, if you don't need uniqueness over several SQL Server instances, just some int-type with a sequence or identity? (As suggested by Mo64.)

The fact that NEWSEQUENTIALID() is "re-seeded" at re-start isn't anything we can prevent, AFAIK.